# Position sticky with direction rtl not working

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper `div.container` inside are `div.children`. I am setting `position:sticky` on the first child. I works fine on `direction:ltr`, however on `direction:rtl` sticky don't work.

I'm not sure if this is a browser bug or my styles are just wrong. Please note that **I don't have access to the html itself**, I can only change the css file and no js as possible.

**Tested on:**
Firefox - Pass ✅
Google Chrome - Fail ❌
Safari - Fail ❌

```css
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container.ltr { direction: ltr; }
.container.rtl { direction: rtl; }

.children {
  display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}
.children.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    background: #f30;
    color: #fff;
}

.container.ltr .children.sticky { left: 0; }
.container.rtl .children.sticky { right: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container ltr">
  <div class="children sticky">1</div>
  <div class="children">2</div>
  <div class="children">3</div>
  <div class="children">4</div>
  <div class="children">5</div>
  <div class="children">6</div>
  <div class="children">7</div>
  <div class="children">8</div>
  <div class="children">9</div>
  <div class="children">10</div>
</div>

<div class="container rtl">
  <div class="children sticky">1</div>
  <div class="children">2</div>
  <div class="children">3</div>
  <div class="children">4</div>
  <div class="children">5</div>
  <div class="children">6</div>
  <div class="children">7</div>
  <div class="children">8</div>
  <div class="children">9</div>
  <div class="children">10</div>
</div>
```

Chromium Bug Report
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1140374

Comment: Encounter the same issue on Chrome. Have you found a way around this?

Comment: No luck even on Chrome 80 even on Safari 13. This only works in Firefox.

Comment: not directly related but might give some things to try from this discussion https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this same issue.
Managed to find a workaround by using an extra container div, which seems to work fine on Chrome (v93), but still fails in Safari (v14.1.2), somehow it moves the sticky element to the left (???)

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container.ltr { 
  direction: ltr;
}

.container.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}

.children {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

.children.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: #f30;
  color: #fff;
}

.container.ltr .children.sticky { 
  left: 0;
}

.container.rtl .children.sticky {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container ltr">
  <div class="children sticky">1</div>
  <div class="children">2</div>
  <div class="children">3</div>
  <div class="children">4</div>
  <div class="children">5</div>
  <div class="children">6</div>
  <div class="children">7</div>
  <div class="children">8</div>
  <div class="children">9</div>
  <div class="children">10</div>
</div>

<div class="container rtl">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="children sticky">1</div>
    <div class="children">2</div>
    <div class="children">3</div>
    <div class="children">4</div>
    <div class="children">5</div>
    <div class="children">6</div>
    <div class="children">7</div>
    <div class="children">8</div>
    <div class="children">9</div>
    <div class="children">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my real use case there are more sticky elements (like the text in each children box), which are working somehow in Safari as well, but could not replicate that with a simple example. I also have a sticky sidebar, which has the same behavior as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky`
has got certain set of limitations in it's behaviour, please refer to https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working

Please check if `position: fixed` serves your purpose.

```css
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container.ltr { direction: ltr; }
.container.rtl { direction: rtl; }

.children {
  display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}
.container.ltr .children:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 102px;
}
.container.rtl .children:nth-child(2){
  margin-right: 102px;
}
.children.sticky {
    /* position: sticky; */
  position :fixed;
    background: #f30;
    color: #fff;
}

/*.container.ltr .children.sticky { left: 0; }
.container.rtl .children.sticky { right: 0; } */
```

```html
<div class="container ltr">
      <div class="children sticky">1</div>
      <div class="children">2</div>
      <div class="children">3</div>
      <div class="children">4</div>
      <div class="children">5</div>
      <div class="children">6</div>
      <div class="children">7</div>
      <div class="children">8</div>
      <div class="children">9</div>
      <div class="children">10</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container rtl">
      <div class="children sticky">1</div>
      <div class="children">2</div>
      <div class="children">3</div>
      <div class="children">4</div>
      <div class="children">5</div>
      <div class="children">6</div>
      <div class="children">7</div>
      <div class="children">8</div>
      <div class="children">9</div>
      <div class="children">10</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I cannot see `2.` here

Comment: The `position: fixed;` will have an issue if the user scrolls vertically. I fixed my issue by changing the `position: sticky;` to `position: absolute;` and add margin as you did on the 2nd child. Even though I fixed my issue, this `position: sticky` on `direction: rtl;` should still be fixed by browser though. 

Comment: the vertical scroll on smaller window will probably need to be addressed for this proposed solution

Comment: yes, it's a noticed issue if parent container of these two elements is scrollable the issue would persist

Answer (score 0):

am also having the same issue but with table scroll with a sticky header above it & so as a temp solution for now, we can us a bit of js to reset the scroll to start from the right as expected.

so lets say we have a div that have a scrollable table and a header that should be sticky when we scroll right/left

```
<div class="scrollable" data-scroll-reset>
    <div class="sticky">
        this should remain still no matter how we scroll to left/right
    </div>

    <table class="rtl">
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<style>
    .scrollable {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    .sticky {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .rtl {
        direction: rtl;
    }
</style>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll-reset]').forEach((e) => {
        e.scrollLeft = 10000
    })
})
</script>
```

> both `data-scroll-reset` & `rtl` should be added on condition, otherwise it will mess the scrolling when the direction is changed to `ltr`.